# The next step in learning real & complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, soft-question, self-learning, education

So I recently finished studying Spivak's calculus (excluding the chapter on construction of the real number system) and I'm almost done with Abbott's understanding analysis, what should my next step be? I had a look at Rudin's book and the topics seem so random to me, as in I feel like there is a gap that needs to be filled before diving into Rudin.

So, I'm after some suggestions in regards to my next step, is there a textbook(s) that can bridge the gap between the textbooks I mentioned above and Rudin's book or should I just 'fight' my way through it? Any advice or suggestions will highly be appreciated.

p.s; please keep in mind that this is for self-studying, I'm talking my first 'official' course in real and complex analysis later next year and I want to have a very good grasp on analysis at an undergraduate level ( or even basic grad level) by then.

**Here, I'm referring to Real And Complex analysis by Walter Rudin**

Comment: "Rudin's book" is an ambiguous reference. Please specify _which_ book by Rudin you're talking about.

Comment: Apologies, it has been edited.

Comment: You shouldn't visit *Real and Complex Analysis* yet. Take a look at *Principles* first.

Comment: Ooookkkayyy, now that looks much more inviting. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is still true that Rudin's textbooks have rather terse writing.  Some students like this, others not (unless they have an instructor to help them by amplifying things when needed).

Comment: @GEdgar okay, so I think Principles of mathematical analysis by Rudin is what I'm going to start studying but if you could perhaps recommend a supplementary book that is not as concise as Rudin's, it would be great

Comment: For studying Rudin's *Principles* on your own, be sure to get Bergman's supplementary exercises ... https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Spivak's *Calculus*, a reasonable next step would be *one* of:

1. *Calculus, Vol. 2* by Apostol (especially if you need quick acquaintance with multivariable calculus for physics or other reasons)
2. *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol
3. *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin
4. *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich (perhaps starting partway through Volume 1)
5. *Advanced Calculus* by Loomis and Sternberg

Any of the last four would be more than adequate preparation for Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

If you have no prior acquaintance with multivariable calculus, but would like to study it at a relatively high level, then Zorich's book might be your best choice. Books 2, 3, and 5 prove the main theorems of multivariable calculus but aren't a good introduction to it. Only books 4 and 5 do a good job on differential forms, Stokes' theorem in a general setting, etc. Only Zorich addresses general topology rather than just metric spaces.